# Rekeying a Tor circuit

Tags: security, protocol, encryption

Is it possible to rekey a connection between a Tor client and a relay? By rekey I mean perform the usual x25519 key exchange to change the session key on the fly, without tearing the circuit down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible yet. [Proposal 262](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/proposals/262-rekey-circuits.txt) is still open and there is no other rekey mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. This proposal seems to be specifically for AEZ, and I recall the decision was to consider ChaCha20-Poly1305 instead, so the prop may not get much traction.